# Firefox Cookie Popup Hell

Tags: firefox

Is there a way to close all these "Confirm setting cookie" popups at once:

[image: confirm setting cookie popup hell]

Currently whenever this happens, I spend a half-hour clicking until all the boxes disappear.

Comment: What cookie or privacy-related extensions have you installed (if any), and what are your settings now in `Edit > Preferences > Privacy > History`?

Comment: Under `Privacy > History`, I have `Keep until` set to `ask me every time`. I recognize that this causes the behaviour. But I don't want to change that setting. Rather, I'd like to find a way to clear these popups all at once when this happens.

Comment: A quick Google search of '[confirm setting cookie](http://www.google.com/search?&q=Confirm+setting+cookie)' reveals this to be a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=515521), reported years ago. Unfortunately that makes it [off-topic](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions) for Ask Ubuntu, but I do hope that gets patched soon. Sounds frustrating. You might consider a cookie managing extension as a workaround, or just set FF to clear them all when you close it.

Comment: Sigh. I can't help thinking there must be some command line way to wipe them all out.